MongoDB update need to calculate no of installment between two date
I am new to Mogo if anyone can point out what is wrong with my code it will be a great help to me. I want to update no of installments in months between two days. My code is with pastebin. I am using moment.js to find the diffrence between two date in months.  I had two date fields maturityDate and sanctionedDate and want to store diffrene between two dates into field named noOfInstallment .
router.get("/fix", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Loan.updateMany(
    {},
    {
      $set: {
        noOfInstallment: moment(new Date("$maturityDate")).diff(
          moment(new Date("$sanctionedDate")),
          "months",
          true
        ),
      },
    }
  );
 
  res.send(data);
});


better if you can provide how your documents look like. i dont think you can do do moment(new Date("$maturityDate")) since $maturityDate is mongo side related and moment runs on the node server. so you will have to do the date diff within the mongo query using mongo date operations

Use $dateDiff

You cannot access fields in native JavaScript. One solution would be this one:
db.loan.updateMany(
    {},
    [{
      $set: {
        noOfInstallment: {
          $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$maturityDate",
          endDate: "$sanctionedDate",
          unit: "month"
          }
        }        
      }
    }]
  );

Some other notes: moment.js is deprecated, you should not use it in new projects.
There is no reason for moment(new Date("$maturityDate")). I assume maturityDate is a Date field. It does not make any sense to use new Date(...) on a value which is already a Date.
Another solution could be this one:
db.loan.find({}).forEach( x => {
   db.load.updateOne(
     {_id: x._id}, 
     {$set: {
        noOfInstallment: moment(x.maturityDate).diff(
         moment(x.sanctionedDate),
         "months",
         true
       )
     } }
   );
})

However updateMany should have better performance.
